# ReaderWriterLockSlim - Unclear Exception Message

Tags: c#, locking

I'm getting the following exception being thrown in my C# service:

Write lock may not be acquired with read lock held. This pattern is prone to deadlocks. Please ensure that read locks are released before taking a write lock. If an upgrade is necessary, use an upgrade lock in place of the read lock..

```
 Stack trace:    at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLockCore(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLock(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.EnterWriteLock()
```

I'm trying to understand what this means. I believe it means that a thread in my app has already acquired a read lock on an object and the same thread is now trying to acquire a write lock on the same object. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that understanding is correct.